# Page Styling (css) does not appear in the new Theme implementation (descendant of Luma Theme)

Tags: magento2, theme, css, static-content, grunt

I just created empty theme which is descendant of Luma theme. but unfortunately the styling is not appear:

[image]

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Senheng Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/Luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Senheng/default', __DIR__);
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**Pending requests, takes minutes to be done.**
[image]
[image]

Could somebody help me how to fix this issue ?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check console for the errors? attached console error screenshot as well.

Comment: I checked on browser all requests returned 200, wait a second for snapshot

Comment: @SaphalJha I have update question with snapshot

Comment: some are pendings, send those full url

Comment: after about 10 minutes everything is 200

Comment: here is the full url sample http://senheng.local/static/version1557377010/frontend/Senheng/default/id_ID/mage/translate-inline.js

Comment: I mate, I just switch the Theme back to Luma and then switch it back to my custom Theme and then everything is working now.

Comment: ahh, sounds good

Comment: thanks for your help by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggled about 2 hours more with this weird issue I just fixed it by set theme back to luma and then set it back to my custom theme, and now my custom theme is working well.

I also run following command (but i am not sure does it matter or not):

```
grunt exec:default
grunt less:default
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run Below Query in mysql, then try again:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```